# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, tomcat, gitlab

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources(default-resources) on project ocean-pms: /opt/gitlab/ocean_pms/target/classes/ocean/message/message-common_az.properties (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

i want jenkins build!!!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.